# Can GCC for ARM flag this as a warning: A != B;

Tags: gcc

Recently, I was doing a review of some of my code and I found two instances where I mistakenly typed != instead of |=.

I was of the opinion that GCC might issue a warning for a non-executable instruction as A != B;

I say non-executable because != is not an assignment operator but a logical operator.

Is there an option that can flag this type of dumb mistake?

I don't know how the code worked properly since I was setting some bits that controlled flash programming -- luckily I caught it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GCC 8 warns for me:

```
void
f1 (int *a, int b)
{
  *a != b;
}

void
f2 (int *pa, int b)
{
  int a = *pa;
  a != b;
  *pa = a;
}

int f3 (void);

void
f4 (int *pa)
{
  int a = *pa;
  a != f3 ();
  *pa = a;
}
```

Results in:

```
t.c: In function ‘f1’:
t.c:4:6: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
   *a != b;
   ~~~^~~~
t.c: In function ‘f2’:
t.c:11:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
   a != b;
   ~~^~~~
t.c: In function ‘f4’:
t.c:21:5: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
   a != f3 ();
   ~~^~~~~~~~
```

`f4` receives a different warning because calling `f3` is a side effect.

See the documentation of the [`-Wunused-value` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunused-value).

Comment: You did *a != b;   Try a !=b;

Comment: That does not make a difference for me.

Comment: Thanks - I did not have that warning ignored and it did not present a warning.

Comment: It must be something else then. You'll have to come up with a small example and add it to your question.